# Updating A Spring Bean In Running Time

Tags: spring

A Spring bean is defined as the following:

```
@Bean(name="foo")
public Map<CompositeKey, Set<String>> fooData() {

  return ...; // getting a data from DB
}
```

Now, I need to be able to update the bean in case any related data update in DB. So, I have a controller

```
@PutMapping("/foo")
public List<Foo> updated(){

   // step 1: fetching data from DB
   // step 2: update the bean in ApplicationContext?
   // step 3: return the updated data
  return ...;
}
```

I only can see a getBean method in the ApplicationContext. How to update the bean in the application context?

Comment: You can't change a bean. But you can change the state of a bean: bea.setFooDate(newData). Beware however of thread safety. I wonder why you dont simply query your database every time you need data. That's what a database is for.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't get a bean from the context. Spring is a dependency injection framework. You're supposed to inject the bean where you need it.

Comment: That is a system configuration data. It rarely get changed. It is hold as a bean also for the performance reason.

Comment: Ah, premature optimization... the root of all evil.

Comment: It loads the whole table data in a form of a Spring bean into memory. This type of operation shall not be executed too often. It certainly isn't the only way to implement the function.